# How to improve this code (array data filtration)

Tags: javascript, html

There is a code that filters the array with the specified parameters and outputs the result to the console. In this case, the code makes filter and displays all colors : 'red' and the number: 10 in the objects that fill the array.

The code works, but the problem will arise when the check-boxes will be more than two. I tried to use the loop, but nothing works. Help to refine the code, to avoid to list the inputs by index. There should be one filter function that would perform a common task.

```js
var colorsAndNumbers = [{
    color: 'red',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'yellow',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'black',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  }
]

var form = document.querySelector('.filters');
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filters input'));

var formChangeHandler = function() {

  var newList = colorsAndNumbers.filter(function(item) {
    if (inputs[0].checked) {
      return item.color === inputs[0].value;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }).

  filter(function(item) {
    if (inputs[1].checked) {
      return item.number === +inputs[1].value;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log(newList);
}

form.addEventListener('change', formChangeHandler);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form action="#" class="filters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="red" id="color">
    <label class="feature" for="color">Color Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="10" id="number">
    <label for="number">Number 10</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/russian_stan/wpm8q51r/

Comment: You have accepted wrong answer as the best answer. **This answer does not achieve the task independent of how many checkboxes you have.** **Please read**: [What should you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formChangeHandler = function () {

  var newList = colorsAndNumbers.filter(function (item) {
    var colours=inputs.filter(function(i){
            return (i.id==='color' && i.checked);
    });

    var numbers=inputs.filter(function(i){
            return (i.id==='number' && i.checked);
    });
    var selectedColours=colours.map(i=>i.value);
    var selectedNumbers=numbers.map(i=>i.value)

    return ((selectedColours.length == 0 || selectedColours.indexOf(item.color) > -1) && (selectedNumbers.length == 0 || selectedNumbers.indexOf(item.number.toString()) > -1));
  });

  console.log(newList);
}
```

It is maintaining two arrays with the selected color and numbers and will filter on the selected values. We can have multiple check boxes for the values and it will automatically filter based on the selected filters.

Comment: Although the code may work, the answer would be more useful if you explain what have you changed, and why.

Comment: It is maintaining two arrays with the selected color and numbers and will filter on the selected values. We can have multiple check boxes for the values and it will automatically filter based on the selected filters.

Comment: And you should [edit] the post to add more information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following reduce function to achieve the task:

```
var newList  = inputs.reduce(
(acc,input, i) => {
if(i%2 ==0  && input.checked && inputs[i+1].checked){ 
acc.push({color:input.value,number:inputs[i+1].value}
)} 
 return acc;
}, 
[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer of your question is an answer which achieve the task independent of how many checkboxes you have. This answer achieve this task. And I added one checkbox more.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.filters input');
var colorsAndNumbers =
[
    {color: 'red', number: 10, color2: 'green'},
    {color: 'yellow', number: 10, color2: 'blue'},
    {color: 'red', number: 5, color2: 'green'},
    {color: 'black', number: 5, color2: 'blue'},
    {color: 'red', number: 5, color2: 'blue'}
];

document.querySelector('.filters').addEventListener('change', function()
{
    var i, newList = colorsAndNumbers.slice(0);
    for(i in inputs)
        newList = newList.filter(function(item)
        {
            return inputs[i].checked ? ''+item[inputs[i].id] == inputs[i].value : !0
        })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newList, null, '\t'))
});
```

```html
<form action="#" class="filters">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="red" id="color"> Color Red
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10" id="number"> Number 10
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="green" id="color2"> Color green
 </label>
</form>
```

Comment: And I don't understand why your question wasn't be **right** answered on english SO and on **[russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/847722)** after 24 hours.